# Location of default background image for Oracle ADF Mobile applications

Tags: image, oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile

I am working in Oracle's ADF Mobile framework (specifically, Campus Mobile). There is a standard background image that is displayed when loading data or as a background image, as seen below (the dark, circle pattern - not the loading spinner):

[image: Oracle ADF Mobile background image]

Is it possible to change this image? I cannot locate it anywhere in the deployed application files or as a file that was bundled with JDeveloper.

Comment: You can modify those default images/text by checking out the Skinning part of ADF Mobile

Comment: @User404: I have already looked over that guide extensively - it does not explain how to change this image. I can not locate it in the ADF Mobile extension resources either.

Answer (score 0):

There is a file named amx.css. Check there to see what classes you want/need to override the modify default css.
Check this blog for more info about your particular 'problem':
http://oracleadfmobile.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/amx-activity-indicator/

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, the image I need to change is the background image for the entire page (the dark gradient with the gray circles in both screenshots).

Answer (score 0):

you need to override the css style of this page which is "#bodyPage"
so put the below code in a CSS file and attach it to your Feature:

```
 #bodyPage{

    background-image: url('<PATH_TO_UR_IMG>>') !important;

   }
```

Note: you won't find the images as it's just a black background with an encoded base64 grey dotted image.

or just click on the "Panel Page" from page structure then go to property inspector in inline style write

```
background:#ffffff;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#bodyPage {
    background:#eceded!important;
}

.amx-panelPage {
    background:#eceded url("../images/normal_background_i5@2x.png") repeat;    
}
```

just using 2 css selector to overriding background for AMX Page